# What's the difference among object, active_object, and selected_objects?

Tags: scripting

I am wondering if following statements are true:

- `active_object` is always identical to `object`.
- `active_object`(or `object` if previous statement is true) is always the first one of `selected_objects`. (This seems to be a false statement since if I use `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')` the `active_object` and `object` is not changed while `selected_objects` is empty.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am fairly sure the first is true, but the second isn't.

The list of `selected_objects` is expanded as new objects are added, new selections are added to the end of the list, while manually selecting the last addition will be the active object, so `active_object` is rarely the first in the `selected_objects` list.

There are some conditions that may catch you out.

- When deselecting all objects, the last active object remains active even though it may no longer be selected.
- When setting items as selected with python the active object does not automatically change.
- Select all does not alter the active object.
- Deleting the active object leaves you with no active object.

Comment: Thank you very much for extra information on these three attributes.
But I failed to find the source evidence of "while manually selecting the last addition will be the active object". Can you give me some directions?

Comment: In the 3dview select an object and in the python console enter `bpy.context.selected_objects`, select another object and repeat in console. You will see that the newly selected object will have the lighter outline of the active object and be the last in the selected list. shift select an already select object and it will be active but the list doesn't change. I expect the source is in `source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_select.c`

Answer (score 3):

After I post this question I think I can have a look at
the implementation(`f51a3aedc9540e0bcda4f16deec22e9aa722ef24`) for answer.

Firstly, `active_object` and `object` refer to the same object when you 
try to access either one of them.

The attribute retrieving happens in the function `ed_screen_context`(file `screen_context.c`).
This function performs string matching on the attribute names.
For `active_object` and `object` you can see both of their implementations return `obact`(It is `scene->basact` actually) as result.

Secondly, when you set an active object through `scene.active = ...`,
`active_object` and `object` are assigned by that object.

The call chain of this process is
`SceneObjects_active_set`(file `rna_scene_gen.c`) -> `rna_Scene_active_object_set`(file `rna_scene.c`).
In the function `rna_Scene_active_object_set` you can see the active object is assigned to `scene->basact`.

Finally, `selected_objects` seems to be a totally different thing from `active_object` and `object`.

The selecting of an object happens in function `Object_select_set`(file `rna_object_gen.c`). But I failed to find the relation between `active_object` and `selected_objects` as @sambler said.

---

EDIT: The relation between `selected_objects` and `active_object`/`object` is confirmed.

as @sambler said

> while manually selecting the last addition will be the active object, so active_object is rarely the first in the selected_objects list

A selecting triggered by *manual* action happen in a space operator, rather than in a Python script binding.
So I search this operator in `view3d` space.
I found the operator `VIEW3D_OT_select` in file `view3d_select.c`.
And there is a call chain of
`view3d_select_exec` -> `mouse_select` -> `ED_base_object_activate`.
I see the object activation happens in `ED_base_object_activate`:

`if ((oldbasact != basact) && (is_obedit == false)) {
    ED_base_object_activate(C, basact); /* adds notifier */
}`

Therefore the last selection will be the new active object.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.0 (I didn't check earlier versions), `context.active_object` is **NOT** always the same as `context.object`.

A situation in which this is the case is if you run the code from a `"PROPERTIES"` panel. That happens for example if you run an operator by clicking a button in the properties panel.

Here are two functions to prove what I'm talking about. Simply copy-paste them into a console and run them.

```
def print_objs_1():
    C = bpy.context
    C.area.type ="PROPERTIES"
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    print(C.object)                    # None or some other already existing object
    print(C.active_object)             # New cube
    print(C.view_layer.objects.active) # Same new cube
    C.area.type="CONSOLE"

def print_objs_2():
    C = bpy.context
    obj = C.scene.objects[0]
    C.view_layer.objects.active = None # setting no active object while still in console panel
    C.area.type ="PROPERTIES"
    C.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    print(C.object)                    # None or some other already existing object
    print(C.active_object)             # obj
    print(C.view_layer.objects.active) # also obj
    C.area.type="CONSOLE"
```

(`C.view_layer.objects.active` is the new version of `C.scene.objects.active`, as stated in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124259)

This (limited) information *suggests* that you should either use `active_object` instead of `object` in your scripts as a general rule, or make sure the `C.area.type` isn't of type `"PROPERTIES"` in parts of your code where it counts.